# Number used as an ID in an organization?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

How would you call a number that an organization would use to unequivocally refer to a person (as an internal ID)?
For instance, imagine you are joining a university. A row in the `student` database table may have this structure:

```
first_name  |  last_name  |  file_number |  etc...


John        | Doe         | 002534       | some extra data...
```

Where, once you joined the university, you've been assigned the ID `002534`.
Here I used the expression "file number" to address this internal ID number.

Any ideas on this? For what it's worth, I'm looking for an expression equivalent to the Spanish "número de legajo" ("file number" was a Google translate suggestion).

Regards

Comment: We typically refer to it based on the person's role in the organization. In other words, a number assigned by a school to one of its students is called a *student ID*, a number assigned by a company to one of its employees is called an *employee ID*, and so on. People sometimes also say student ID *number* or employee ID *number*.

Comment: I see. The problem with that approach, is that those words sound too similar to a "database id", and since I'm using it as a database field name (like in the example), I think it may lead to confusion. Anyway, thanks for your comment

Comment: Labels for fields on data-entry screens are governed by application-domain rules. Questions about them are not about English usage or grammar.

Comment: I disagree. I was looking for a general term. The fact that I'm using it in an application has nothing to do with the term itself

Comment: How does "student id" sound similar to "database id"?

Comment: "student id" does not sound like "database id" at all. But, if you use a database PK field called "student_id" (for example), and that table has an organization internal id, with a name related to the business, you can't call that field "student_id". That's why I'd rather use a more general term, instead of a business specific.
Anyway, I accepted @Wyatt's answer, but I chose to use the more general "file_number". Thank you all for your valuable comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @pyobum said, it depends on the role of the specified individual in society. Student's would have a *Student ID*, employees have an *Employee ID*, and even companies have a *Company Database PIN* (in the US). In general terms, file_number is acceptable, but for more specific language, roles must be accounted for.